# change the form target in powermail 1.6.x with typoscript for a specific form

Tags: typo3, typoscript

I have two forms on my page. 
I want to change the target of a form with typoscript. The result should be two different "Thank You for contacting me" pages for two different forms on one site.

I've tried the following Typoscript

```
[globalVar = GP:tx_powermail_pi1|uid55 = 1]
  plugin.tx_powermail_pi1.formaction.typolink.parameter = 299
[else]
  plugin.tx_powermail_pi1.formaction.typolink.parameter = 258
[end]
```

In this case I've made a hidden field with the UID 55 and the value 1.

and the second try:

```
[globalVar = GP:tx_powermail_pi1|mailID < 1613]
  plugin.tx_powermail_pi1.formaction.typolink.parameter = 299
[else]
  plugin.tx_powermail_pi1.formaction.typolink.parameter = 258
[end]
```

In this case I simply check the mailID of the posted form (ID 1612 is form number 1 and ID 1618 is form number 2).

but it does not work. In both cases the target is the page with the id 258.

I've also tried the same with `globalString`.

Typo3 4.6.7 with powermail 1.6.10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want different "Thank you" pages for both forms, then use "Auto-redirect after confirmation-page", which can be found in the plugin-settings (tab "Answer page") of your Powermail forms.